# How do I bypass class extensions when reading from ArcSDE with FME 2014?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, fme-form, classextensions

I'm trying to read Feature Class from our Enterprise Geodatabase and because we have custom class extensions registered on all our our data.

I am not able to set the Reader to bypass the class extensions.

I get this warning in the log

"Unable to read from the table/feature class 'YK_SPATIAL.Buildings'. If 'YK_SPATIAL.Buildings' contains a class extension, make sure it is registered on this computer"

Thanks

Comment: Which reader are you using? I believe the SDE30 reader will bypass geodatabase functionality, but the GEODATABASE_SDE reader will honor it.

Comment: @blah238 Yes, you are right. I never thought those readers were that different.  I was using GEODATABASE_SDE because it allowed me to use ArcSDE connection file.