# FME Error with class extensions

Tags: fme-form, classextensions

Recently I have been getting errors in FME Translations from a geodatabase (Reader) to a GT Viewer Format (Writer).  When I update or import feature types I get this error[image: Translation Error]  I have done updates before with same client data from previous months. Not sure what is going on?

Comment: Check that u're using the correct reader.. also check if there's been any updates to the datamodel of the database reader..

Comment: check the arcgis license is available before running, if there are 2 instances arcgis.exe this can prevent fme getting a valid license.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the SDE30 reader vs. the GEODATABASE_SDE reader, as referenced in the comments of [this post.](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/86048/how-do-i-bypass-class-extensions-when-reading-from-arcsde-with-fme-2014)